# How to pass reference value of factor to glmulti?

Tags: r

When using the package glmulti to fit multiple nested models I want to pass a reference value for a factor (x2: "A", "B"). When fitting a normal glm I would use `relevel(x1,"B")`. This does not work strait away in glmulti, where candidate variables are passed as text.

My attempt:

```
multimodel<- glmulti(y="response", xr= c("x1", "relevel(x2,'A')", "x3", "x4"), 
   data=mydata, level=2, method="g", crit="aicc")
```

Error message:

```
Initialization...
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
attempt to select less than one element
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I just realized that the reordering of factors can be done directly in the data frame before analysis as `mydata$x2<- relevel(mydata$x2,"B")`, which completely removed the specific problem I had with glmulti. Lazy of me not to find this out before posting the Q.

The original call can also be made as a normal glm, which also eliminates the problem:

```
multimodel<- glmulti(response ~ x1 + relevel(x2,"A") + x3 + x4,
   data=mydata, level=2, crit="aicc")
```